# Can one expect the existence of a relevant approach for a proof of the Riemann hypothesis using Mochizuki's theory?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, intuition, riemann-hypothesis, abc-conjecture

Next month at Oxford university, there will have the first workshop outside Asia on the Inter-Universal Teichmuller theory of Shinichi Mochizuki:  http://www.claymath.org/events/iut-theory-shinichi-mochizuki

See this recent paper in *Nature*: [The biggest mystery in mathematics: Shinichi Mochizuki and the impenetrable proof](http://www.nature.com/news/the-biggest-mystery-in-mathematics-shinichi-mochizuki-and-the-impenetrable-proof-1.18509), 07 October 2015.

See also the mathoverflow post: [Philosophy behind Mochizuki's work on the ABC conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/q/106560/34538)

I wanted to post the question in title but I've found an equivalent question posted on Quora 11h ago (without answer), and I think it has its place on mathoverflow, so I just reproduce it below:

> [**How strong is the link between the abc conjecture and the Riemann hypothesis which Mochizuki proposes in his proof of the abc conjecture?**](https://www.quora.com/How-strong-is-the-link-between-the-abc-conjecture-and-the-Riemann-hypothesis-which-Mochizuki-proposes-in-his-proof-of-the-abc-conjecture)
>
> Mochizuki has published a series of 6 papers (as of 11/11/2015) on
>   Inter-Universal Teichmüller Theory on his webpage. In the one which
>   contains the proof of the abc conjecture (4/6), he relates his methods
>   also to the Riemann hypothesis (pages 47-53). Can someone explain how
>   strong this link is? Is there a way to estimate - given the
>   information in this paper - how likely it is that the Riemann
>   hypothesis can be proved using Mochizukis methods?

The main reason why I ask this question today is that one author of the abc conjecture is visiting my institute for 4 months, I've talked with him several times this week, and I discovered by him the polemic around Mochizuki's proof. Moreover because there will have this famous workshop next month, I think it would be a good opportunity to clarify this question also.

Comment: It the paper it says "perhaps some extension of the
theory of the present series of papers — i.e., some sort of
“inter-universal Mellin
transform”
— may be obtained that allows one to relate the theory of the present
series of papers to the Riemann zeta function." This sounds pretty vague. Preceding it there are some more remarks, but it seems very speculative.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a terrible question.  What is the point of speculating on how Mochizuki's work (which no one seems to have seriously evaluated), applies or does not apply to RH?

Comment: The phrase "published a series of 6 papers...on his webpage" significantly  lowers the bar for what it means to "publish".  This highly speculative question has no place on MO.

Comment: What motivates you to ask? Is this something you think will be useful for your own research, or is it sort of idle curiosity?

Comment: @ToddTrimble: The main reason why I ask this question today is that one author of the abc conjecture is visiting my institute for 4 months, I've talked with him several times this week, and I discovered by him the polemic around Mochizuki's proof. Moreover because there will have this famous workshop next month, I think it would be a good opportunity to clarify this question also.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux Thank you! I'm not sure it would help with reopening, but you might consider adding that detail to your question (it's certainly more than 'idle curiosity').

Comment: I think it's fair to say that it has been difficult for most people to get into Mochizuki's work in a serious way and so any discussion on whether it is correct and what the implications to other questions it might have are just premature. Hopefully, next month's workshop will help change this. I think the best thing to do is wait a month.

Comment: I don't think this question is so far fetched. Granville has shown that a suitably generalised version of the ABC conjecture would imply the non-existence of Siegel zeros for quadratic Dirichlet L-functions.

Comment: @DanielLoughran what has this to do with the question how likely it is that  the Riemann hypothesis can be proved using Mochizukis **methods**? The question is of course not far fetched (neither is it terrible, imo), as it is  asking how viable something detailed over a couple of paragraphs of Mochizuki is. But hardly anybody has a good grasp what is even in the papers, so to ask what could be done in addition seems not answerable.  To put this pointedly: as long as "How likely  is it that ABC can be proved using Mochizukis methods?" has no clear answer, questions beyond that seem premature.

Comment: @quid: the CMI conference on Mochizuki's theory has finished yesterday, so it is perhaps the good time to reopen this post.

Comment: Sébastien, I don't know that the status of the question has changed since the conference ended, unless you and/or someone you know have some information which could be added as an answer.

Comment: A link to [some kind of conclusion of that workshop](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/195841/what-is-an-%C3%A9tale-theta-function/223258#223258) was posted today on this site. From it what seems most clear is that  'How likely is it that ABC can be proved using Mochizukis methods?" has no clear answer' is still very much true.

Answer (score 9):

I think Mochizuki himself makes a good exposition of the highly spectulative relation (not much more so that the F_1, [absolute geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69389/riemann-hypothesis-via-absolute-geometry?rq=1), noncommutative geometry, etc approaches, if you ask me) between IUT and the Riemann hypothesis. I'll copy the relevant paragraphs from IUT IV here, for future reference (pages 47 to 52):

(i) [...] In particular, the bound under consideration may be written in the form

$$\frac{1}{6}\cdot h \leq \delta + * \cdot \delta^{1/2} \cdot \log (\delta)$$

where "$*$" is to be understood as denoting a *fixed positive real number*; we observe that the *ratio* $h/\delta$ is always a positive real number which is *bounded below* by the definition of $h$ and $\delta$ and *bounded above* precisely as a consequence of the bound consideration. In this context, it is of interest to observe that the form of the "$\epsilon$ term" $\delta^{1/2}\cdot \log (\delta)$ is
**strongly reminiscent** of the well-known interpretations of the **Riemann hypothesis** in terms of the asymptotic behaviour of the function defined by considering the number of prime numbers below a given number.

Indeed, from the point of view of **weight** [cf. also the discussion of Remark 2.2.2 below], it is natural to regard the [logarithmic] height of a line bundle as an object that has the *same weight* as
**single Tate twist**, or, from a more classical point of view, "$2\pi i$" raised to the *power* $1$. On the other hand, again from the point of view of weights, the variable "*s*" of the *Riemann zeta function* $\zeta (s)$ may be thought of as corresponding precisely to the
*number of Tate twists* under consideration, so a *single Tate twist* correspondes to "$s=1$". Thus, from this point of view, "$s=\frac{1}{2}$", i.e., the *critical line* that appears in the
*Riemann hypothesis*, corresponds precisely to the *square roots* of the [logarithmic] heights under consideration, i.e., to $h^{1/2}$, $\delta^{1/2}$. [...]

(ii) In [vFr], $2, it is conjectured that, in the notation of the discussion of (i),

$$\lim \sup \frac{\log \left(\frac{1}{6}\cdot h - \delta\right)}{\log(h)}=\frac{1}{2}$$

and observed that the "$\frac{1}{2}$" that appears here is **strongly reminiscent** of the "$\frac{1}{2}$" that appears in the **Riemann hypothesis**. [...]

(iii) In the well-known classical theory of the **Riemann zeta function**, the Riemann zeta function is closely related to the
**theta function**, i.e., by means of the **Mellin transform**. In light of the *central role* played by the theta functions in the theory of the present series of papers, it is tempting to hope, especially in the context of the observations of (i), (ii), that perhaps some extensions of the theory of the present series of papers
- i.e., some sort of "**inter-universal Mellin transform**" - may be obtained that allows one to relate the theory of the present series of papers to the Riemann zeta function.

(iv) In the context of the discussion of (iii), it is of interest to recall that, relative to the analogy between *number fields* and *one-dimensional function fields over finite fields*, the theory of the present series of papers may be tought of as being analogous to the theory surrounding the **derivative** of a lifting of the **Frobenious morphism** [cf. the discussion of [IUTchI], $I4; [IUTchIII], Remark 3.12.4]. On the other hand, the analogue of the **Riemann hypothesis** for one-dimensional function fields over finite fields may be proven by considering the elementary geometry of the [graph of the] **Frobenius morphism**. This state of affairs suggest that perhaps some sort of **"integral"** of the theory of the present series of papers could shed light on the Riemann hypothesis in the case of number fields.

(v) One way to summarize the point of view discussed in (i), (ii), and (iii) is as follows: The *asymptotic behaviour* discussed in (i) suggests that perhaps one should expect that the *inequality* constituted by well-known interpretations of the **Riemann hypothesis** in terms of the asymptotic behaviour of the function defined by considering the number of prime numbers below a given number may be obtained as some sort of *"restriction"*

$$\text{(ABC inequality)|}_\text{canonical number}$$

of some sort of *"ABC inequality"* [i.e., some sort of bound of the sort obtained in Corollary 2.2, (ii)] to some sort of *"canonical number"* [i.e., where the term "number" is to be understood as referring to an *abc* sum]. Here, the descriptive "canonical" is to be understood as expressing the idea that one is not so much interested in considering a *fixed explicit "number/abc sum"*, but rather some sort of *suitable abstraction* of the sort of sequence of numbers/*abc* sums that gives rise to the lim sup value of "$\frac{1}{2}$" discussed in (ii). Of course, it is by no means clear precisely how such an "abstraction" should be formulated, but the idea is that it should represent

> some sort of **average** over **all possible addition operations**

in the number field [in this case $\mathbb{Q}$] under consideration or [perhaps equivalently]

> some sort of **"arithmetic measure or distribution"** constituted by
>   such a collection of **all possible addition operations** that somehow
>   amounts to a sort of arithmetic analogue of the measure that gives
>   rise to the classical **Mellin transform**

[i.e., that appears in the discussion of (iii)].

[vFr] M. van Frankenhuijsen, About the ABC conjecture and an alternative (2012)